# Transformer stage and dynamic files structure

Tags: datastage

I'm reading a datafile that's being generated from a data source that's denormalizing data into a flat file. As an example:

```
References,Reference_Count,Reference_1,Reference_2
"abc,def",2,abc,def
abc,1,abc,
```

This would be easy to load in, except that at some point, we're going to get an entry that has a third reference, which will then include a `Reference_3` column in the input file, and I want to be able to process that column automatically, without having to re-write the Transformer.

The `References` column *does* contain all the data, concatenated from the different columns; but it's inconsistent - there are columns that use comma separators; some with newlines; and some with no separator at all, which means it can't be used for this.

I've tried using a loop in the Transformer stage, using the `Reference_Count` field. This gives the correct number of iterations, but I can't figure out how to set up the appropriate column as a loop variable. Using:

```
Link."Reference_" : @ITERATIION
```

generates a syntax error; while:

```
"Reference_": @ITERATION
```

passed `Reference_1` - the name of the column, and not its value.

Is what I'm trying to do possible in DataStage? I can't see much in the documentation about using dynamically-named columns.

Comment: When reading the rows from the sequential stage, did you check "First row is column names"?